# Where can I find a manual for learning the fundamental background of LaTeX source?

Tags: documentation, sourcecode

I would like to know if there is some manual from which I can learn the bases of LaTeX programming language. I need something universal, not related to some specific package or class, that at the end allow me to have a look at various source files, to understand the code in them and even to modified some file or to create my own source files of packages or classes.

I am not a beginner user of LaTeX. I have written a lot of documents using LaTeX with some standard classes and packages and with more exotic ones. What I want is not a manual that tells me how to write a document with LaTeX but how LaTeX works at its bases.

For example what are macros and how to use them, how to use command like `\def`, `\if`, `\ifx`, `\fi`, `\global`, `\let`, `\relax`, the key `@`, `\DeclareOption`, `\begingroup`,  etc... (I have only open the file `article.cls` and check for command that I don't know..)

Comment: Have a look at this question [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11)

Comment: @ach: I checked your link but there I find only manuals for "writing documents using LaTeX". Maybe my question is not so clear, I'll try to modify it

Comment: In which case, look at source2e.pdf, describing the LaTeX source in detail (found on most *TeX installation via `texdoc source2e`).

Comment: You're lucky: http://profs.sci.univr.it/~gregorio/introtex.pdf (in Italian) ;-)

Comment: You can read the source code of `TeXBook` that is available from CTAN [here](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbook).

Comment: Thank you egreg! Also in Italian, very good! It is a good example of what type of manual I am looking for

Comment: @ach source2e.pdf seems interesting too

Comment: @egreg I didn't know you wrote such an awesome manual in italian!!!. Thanks for it and for pointing it out in the comment. I'll start reading it immediately. I have surely tons of things to learn from it.

Comment: On the use of `@`, you might want to start with [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351) and [When to use @ in an \if statement](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27803) (there are also others!).

Comment: Why not use the Latex companion?

Comment: @egreg: unlucky for those of us who don't speak Italian :( Is there an English version/equivalent?

Comment: @martina because it is a "how to write a document with LaTeX" manual and not a "how does LaTeX internally works" one. This is an opinion, it can be wrong, I have only read the ToC of LaTeX Companion

Comment: Duplicate of [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming?noredirect=1&lq=1) I guess Just for cross-linking purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LaTeX2e kernel and LaTeX2e packages are written in a mixture of TeX primitives and some plain TeX macros, LaTeX2e document-level commands, LaTeX2e package/class commands and 'internal' code. Documentation is therefore split up:

- *The TeXbook* for TeX primitives and 'utility' plain TeX macros ([*TeX by Topic*](http://texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic) also highly recommended)
- *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System* for document level commands
- [Class guide](http://texdoc.net/pkg/clsguide) for package/class commands
- Individual `.dtx` files for 'internal' commands (may have documentation, may just have code)

As such, there is no one document to read to understand programming LaTeX2e. One of the aims of the LaTeX3 Project is to provide a single programming layer for the future: [`expl3`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/expl3).

Answer (score 0):

The [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) has information about [macros](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros) and [plain TeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX), although I don't know if they'll be detailed enough for your needs. But it might be worth a look, and you can always add something if necessary!