# TeX Usage of the Ampersat (@)

Tags: tex-core

I've had trouble finding easily accessible information on what exactly the ampersat does in TeX- it seems to be used frequently in the implementations of the commands I use, yet I've never had to use it. (Granted I've only used LaTeX) What does the ampersat do in TeX?

Comment: I thought the @ sign was called an "ampersat"... Apparently not that often?

Comment: @Anthony If given a name, it's usually a 'commercial at', with 'ampersat' being a name that's been suggested based on analogy with ampersand (&).

Comment: 'Commercial at'? What's commercial about it?

Comment: Perhaps also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/when-to-use-in-an-if-statement

Comment: @Anthony The symbol was introduced for producing invoices and the like: '10 widgets @ 10 p each'. (It's come down to us from the days of the telegraph.)

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Exciting!